# Work with Concurrency Tokens shadow column with InMemory database in .NET

Tags: .net, sqlite, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I'm trying to create unit tests for the database repository class using the InMemory Sqlite database. I have one of the entities with the [Concurrency Tokens column](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/concurrency.html?tabs=data-annotations) named `xmin`.
[image]

This column configured in DbContext this way:
[image]

And then I'm trying to setup in memory context for unit tests:
[image]

In TestDataBuilder I've filled this column with some value.
Here's an error I'm getting:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that

> NOT NULL constraint failed

which happens upon saving null for not nullable values. You will need to find out what specific value/field is null and make sure that you will save valid data.

Comment: As I can see in the error message it says that I have NOT NULL constraint for Identities.xmin column. The type of this column is uint (non nullable). And as you can see from my last screen, I'm filling this field with some value

Comment: @HannaHolasava good point. Can you share the relevant part of your code as text? I know you have some screenshots, but the useful debug info covers parts of the code.

Comment: Has the author found a solution for that, and if so, can you share it?

Comment: Julian, I wasn't able to find an issue yet :(
I just skipped this code from unit testing